# How do you convert an entire webm audio directory to an opus audio with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

What I'm trying to do is, by using ffmpeg, convert all webm audio files in an directory to opus audio files, store to an another directory.

Have no idea, just messed up by search results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tis bot iz crazy